# already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am implementing a website by laravel.There is a problem that some times it shows some error `already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections` how to solve this?[image]

Comment: set in `app/config/database.php` `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` to `false`

Comment: Thanks for reply.i am checking @Xorifelse

Comment: not found something like `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` .iam using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 2):

there is another question may solve your problem

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47131/how-to-get-rid-of-maximum-user-connections-error

Answer (score 0):

You can pass PDO options to the connection (it is not well documented, but the code won't lie: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#L33) in **app/config/database.php** like this:

```
...

'connections' => [
        ...

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'engine'    => null,
            'dump_command_path' => '/opt/mysql/bin', 
            'options' => [
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false //@todo
            ]
        ],

        ...
```

Comment: Some more insigth into presisten connections: "Are PHP persistent connections evil?" https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/11/12/are-php-persistent-connections-evil/

Comment: Will this connect N times if I make N quesries in a single call? I'm wondering how this impacts performance